# Reorder rows in TClientDataSet

Tags: delphi

In order to show my data in some order, I have ORDER column. So I can move up and down rows. That is already working, I just swap ORDER number for the affected rows. My problem is, when I delete a row, I need to reorder all other rows. To show the rows in the proper order I use the .IndexFieldNames := 'ORDER', but when I iterate through all rows and assign the new ORDER number, with active index its pretty slow. When I remove the .IndexFieldNames := '', then the rows are not in the correct order anymore, and the new order is wrong.

Here is my code:

```
class procedure TDataModuleEx.ReOrderColumn(const aDataSet: TClientDataSet;
  const aFieldName: string; aResetClone: Boolean);
var
  clone: TClientDataSet;
  newOrderNo: Integer;
begin
  newOrderNo := 0;
  clone := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
  try
    clone.CloneCursor(aDataSet, aResetClone);
    clone.IndexFieldNames := aFieldName;
    clone.IndexFieldNames := ''; //Indexed Edit is too slow
    clone.First;
    while not clone.eof do
    begin
      Inc(newOrderNo);
      clone.Edit;
      clone.FieldByName(aFieldName).AsInteger := newOrderNo;
      clone.Post;

      clone.Next;
    end;
  finally
    clone.Free;
  end;
end;
```

How can I reorder my rows after one is deleted efficiently?

Comment: It looks like your question is missing something: **In itself there is no reason why the numbers in an index should be sequential**. 1,2,3,5,6,7 will work fine, so you don't need to edit your records. **Why do you want the ORDER values to be sequential?**

Comment: As you set IndexFieldNames to '' when you set the Order field, it seems that the data initially in the dataset has been inserted in the order you require.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Jan Doggen: You are right, it will work, but I think it's better approche to eliminate the gap. It's just my opinion.

Comment: @MartynA: Actually I thought, when I first order my records by IndexFieldNames := 'ORDER' and then delete the index, the order will remain, but that's not the case unfortunatelly.

Comment: @markus_ja Sorry but it's nonsense to take all this trouble for *an opinion*. That is called over-engineering. If you have no reason for them to be sequential, you don't have an issue here.

Comment: I belive the main performance botleneck is that you are storing the index for new order directly into existing records. This causes the database to update the whole records for this. So perhpas you might want to create a new database table which will be storing pair of original record index and new record index. Another advantage of such approach is that you could have multiple of such tables for multiple different orders.

Answer (score 0):

I made some testing on a table with 10 000 records. Procedure ReOrderColumn made renumbering for about 3 seconds. ClientDataSet. ApplyUpdate took about 30 seconds.

**Total about 33 seconds**.

I wrote stored procedure in Firebird database which made renumbering for **about 3 seconds**.

```
SET TERM ^ ;

create or alter procedure REORDER
as
declare variable ID integer;
declare variable I integer;
BEGIN
  i = 0;
  FOR
    select new_table.id
    from new_table
    order by FORDER
    INTO :ID
    as cursor tcur
  DO
  BEGIN
    i = :i + 1;
    update new_table t set t.forder = :i
    where current of tcur;
  END
 END^

 SET TERM ; ^
```

From Delphi

```
procedure Reorder;
begin
  //Apply changes to server
  dm1.ClientDataSet1.ApplyUpdates(0); 
  //execute stored procedure
  dm1.spReorder.ExecProc; <--- ABOUT 3 SEC FOR 10 000 records
  //Refresh dataset
  dm1.ClientDataSet1.Close;
  dm1.ClientDataSet1.Open;
end;
```

Comment: This assumes that the CDS is getting its data from a server, which is not necessarily the case.

Comment: I suppose that if CDS has to get data from a file or something else(not from a server) it could be mentioned in the question.

Comment: @ValMarinov: This is a nice solution, I will keep it in my mind. I would prefer doing it in the CDS. But it seems that is not possible.